# Programming with Lego Mindstorms EV3

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, ev3

I know this question was asked in the past, but I want an up-to-date answer.

What is the best way to program with the NXT with a oriented object programming language?  Ideally C#, C++ or Java (maybe Python).

I've search a bit, but I have difficulty to find what is popular today.

I'm really interested in Mindstorms, but I don't want to program with boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we did NXT programming in university we used NXC (http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nbc/) as our primary language.

This is a C-stlye language, not exactly object-oriented, but seeing that NXT programming is practically equivalent to microcontroller programming, C is much better suited to this task in my opinion. In C you get a much clearer main loop that controls your robot, and I can't really see what benefits would object orientation bring to a platform that is clearly restricted in both input/output capabilities and computational resources.

But if you really need object oriented design, take a look at LeJOS: http://www.lejos.org/

Comment: The last update of NXC is 2011, I'm not sure it's still maintained.  LeJOS seem to be updated frequently, I'll probably try this one.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++ with [c4ev3](http://c4ev3.github.io), also available as Eclipse Plugin.

If you are ok with sending the commands remotely, you can even use any language that supports `popen()` like functionality, (which includes every useful language out there, with some bash-fu even Brainfuck). Check out [moveEv3.pl](https://github.com/c4ev3/ev3duder/blob/master/moveEv3.pl).